# Unity directional light for a day night cycle on a hex sphere

Tags: unity, lighting

So I am trying to create a Day Night cycle on a sphere but it doesn't work the way I want it to.
As the model is hex tiled, you see the edges of the hex tiles also lit up like below. I am using a directional light source for the same.

[image]
I don't want the above effect. I want it to ignore the edges and just be a straight line instead. Something like below

[image]

Is there a way inside Unity that I could achieve this effect just using the lights?

Comment: Have the tried the solution to this similar (though may not be exactly the same) problem asked here? http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/345694/3d-tile-lighting.html

Comment: That's going to have something to do with the vertex normals for each tile of the hex-sphere. Rather than having the vertex normals calculated by the hex surface-plane (which is standard), your going to want to calculate them based on the point on the sphere the vertex is. So how are you creating the hexes? Imported tiles being duplicated along a sphere? Procedurally generated?

Comment: The entire hex sphere model was given to me by an artist. He made the entire model in Blender. Each hex is a separate object inside Unity

Comment: Would this be a problem with the model in Blender itself or could it be fixed inside Unity? Maybe by writing a shader? I have not been able to figure out what exactly is causing this problem